# Is (F, G) → G ◦ F linear or bilinear?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We just started the concept of "bilinear" in class and I don't think i totally get it.
Lets say U, V, W are 3 vector spaces and C is a map where
C :
L(U, V ) × L(V, W) → L(U, W)
(F, G) → G ◦ F
Can anyone briefly explain if C is linear or bilinear?

Comment: Have you try to use linearity or bilinearity definitions to see what happens? If you do it... you should be almost done.

Comment: thank you i tried using the definitions and it was quite straight forward. c is linear

Answer (score 0):

I have read you comment in the post, but I hace to tell you that $C$ is bilinear. Since the domain of $C$ is $\mathcal L(U,V)\times\mathcal L(V,W)$, when you take an element of that domain, it is of the form $(f,g)$. Note that in each entry, you can sum and multiply by scalars, and, then, apply $C$. Indeed, given $f,g:U\to V$, $h:V\to W$ linear maps and $\lambda \in\mathbb K$, then $s:=\lambda f+g:U\to V$ is linear and we can apply $C$ to $h$ and $s$. We have: $C(s,h)=h\circ s=h\circ(\lambda f+g)$, evaluating that composition in a LM arbitrary point $p\in U$, one obtains $h\circ(\lambda f+g)(p)=\lambda h\circ f(p)+h\circ g(p)= (\lambda h\circ f+h\circ g)(p)$. That is, $h\circ(\lambda f+g)=h\circ\lambda f+h\circ g$. So, finally, $C$ is linear in the first entry. Analogously, you can get that it is linear in the second entry. Therefore, $C$ is bilinear.